# How to get those data using with ajax json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

The following coding is the out come of an other page php echo

```
user_list.php:

$myarray=array();
...
...
$myjson = json_encode($myarray);
echo $myuser->searchUser($myjson);
```

and the result of html is:

```
[{"userID":"1","username":"\u9ec3\u9ec3\u9ec3",
"sex":"F","password":"1bbd886460827015e5d605ed44252251",
"emails":"test@test.com","regdate":"2015-11-03 00:00:00",
"dob":"1994-11-02","educationID":"6","positionID":"1",
"home":"12341234","mobile":"21800000","address":"AC2 5\/F Rm5501","grade":"Y1","status":"0","office_tel":"41234123",
"inviter":null,"inviter_relation":null,"believe":"0",
"remark":null}]
```

As I know, here is a array not an object. So how i can get those data in other page like this?

```
$(".edituser").click(function () {
        var user = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
                  url:"user_list.php",
                  data:"userID="+user,
                  type : "POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success:function(data){  
                  console.log(data);
                  },
                  error:function(xhr){
                    alert('Ajax request fail');
                  }
                  });
    });
```

How get i get the data in ajax? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to access the object.

**1. Ajax response.**

```
$.ajax({
  url:"your_file.php",
  type : "POST",
  data : your_data,
  dataType: "json",
  success:function(data){  
    // Retrieve the object
    var result = data[0];
    // Grab username from the object
    console.log(result['username']);
  },
  error:function(xhr){
    alert('Ajax request fail');
  }
});
```

**2. Server side script**

```
$yourArray = array();
$yourJson = json_encode($yourArray);
$userData  = $yourJson->searchUser($yourJson);
$jsonData = json_decode($userData);
// Ouput the inner contents
echo json_encode($jsonData[0]);
```

Comment: @YukwongTsang Glad to know, cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change the format in the following method.

```
$myuser->searchUser($myjson)
```

OR

Use the 0 index to get the JSON object.

```
resultData[0] //will return JSON object
```

I will recommend changing the format in PHP method. All the best!